# Capturar el Checked de un CheckBox dentro de un Datagrid desde el ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Tengo un requerimiento en `WPF`, hice un `ViewModel` llamado **AsignaFacturasVM** para mi View, en el que tengo un `Label` que está enlazado a una propiedad `float` llamada **ImporteAcumulado** de mi `ViewModel` y también tengo un `Datagrid` cuyo `ItemSource` es una propiedad de mi `ViewModel` que es una `ObservableCollection` llamada **CuentasxCobrar** que entre sus propiedades contiene un `float` llamado **Importe** (que edito dentro del `Datagrid` con un `TextBox`) y un `bool` llamado Seleccionada (que edito dentro del `DataGrid` con un `CheckBox`).

Lo que necesito hacer, es que cada vez que el usuario haga Check en algún `CheckBox`, se actualice la propiedad **ImporteAcumulado**, sumando todos los **Importe** de los renglones del `DataGrid` que tengan **Seleccionada** en `true`.

Espero haberme explicado.

Para esto, tengo una Función dentro de mi `ViewModel` que se encarga de acumular estos importes dependiendo de si está Seleccionada en true, pero no he podido encontrar cómo y en qué momento lanzar esta función, los datos en mi colección y en mi `ViewModel` se actualizan correctamente dependiendo de lo que el usuario modifique en el `View`, solamente me falta hacer que se realice correctamente el cálculo del **ImporteAcumulado**...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dentro de mi ViewModel cs:

```
    private ObservableCollection<CuentasxCobrarCL> _cuentasxcobrar;
    public ObservableCollection<CuentasxCobrarCL> CuentasxCobrar
    {
        set
        {
            _cuentasxcobrar = value;
            ActualizaImporteAcumulado();
            OnPropertyChanged("CuentasxCobrar");
            OnPropertyChanged("ImporteAcumulado");
        }
        get { return _cuentasxcobrar; }
    }

        private void ActualizaImporteAcumulado()
    {
        _importeacumulado = 0;
        foreach (var item in _cuentasxcobrar)
        {
            _importeacumulado += item.seleccionada ? item.importepago : 0;
        }
        OnPropertyChanged("ImporteAcumulado");
    }
```

En mi XAML:

```
<sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Seleccionar" Width="95" CanUserSort="False"  >
<sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <CheckBox Name="chkseleccionada"                                                       
                    IsChecked="{Binding seleccionada, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
            NotifyOnValidationError=True,
            ValidatesOnExceptions=True, 
            ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True, 
            ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"  />
    </DataTemplate>
</sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
<sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding seleccionada, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
            NotifyOnValidationError=True,
            ValidatesOnExceptions=True, 
            ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True, 
            ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />                                            
    </DataTemplate>        
</sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
```

Parte de mi CuentasxCobrarCL.cs:

```
    public class CuentasxCobrarCL : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int idcli { get; set; }
    public DateTime fecha { get; set; }
    public DateTime fechadepago { get; set; }
    #region public float importepago
    private float _importepago;
    public float importepago 
    {
        get
        { return _importepago; }
        set
        {
            _importepago = value;
            _saldonuevo = _adeudo - _importepago;
            OnPropertyChanged("saldonuevo");
            OnPropertyChanged("importepago");
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region public bool seleccionada
    private bool _seleccionada;
    public bool seleccionada
    {
        get
        { return _seleccionada; }
        set
        {
            _seleccionada = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("seleccionada");
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region PropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Hola Candy, te recomiendo que adicional a la explicación que has dado en la pregunta, agregues el error que te presenta y el código actual que llevas realizado, y de este modo te podrían ayudar con mas facilidad. :)

Comment: Cyndy podras mostrar lo que contiene la clase CuentasxCobrarCL, sobre todo para el valor booleano y el evento que recalcula...

Comment: Cyndy y @J.Rodríguez lean esto porfa https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/448/324. el resaltado de todas las palabras claves fuera del codigo hace que sea mas dificil de leer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay que hacer un par de cambios para que funcione. Lo principal, es saber que observable collection no dispara el metodo on change al cambiar algun valor de los objetos que contiene, si no que solo se dispara cuando la observablecollection cambia en si misma.

Debemos tener una forma de saber cuando la clase hija se actualiza, y avisarle al padre, quien tiene la observableCollection, que tiene que actualizar el valor del check.

El problema? no hay una forma simple de hacer esto. Debemos armar un evento por cada vez que la clase hija cambia, y esto es un problema, porque debemos tener un evento por cada hijo.

En tu caso, vamos a hacer otra cosa.

Necesitamos agregar a tu VM una propiedad que sepa que item esta seleccionado en la grilla, y cuando se seleccione otro item en la grilla, recalcular el total.

Agrega a tu grilla lo siguiente:

```
SelectedItem="{Binding ItemSeleccionado, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Luego, a tu vm, agrega lo siguiente:

```
CuentasxCobrarCL _ItemSeleccionado;
public CuentasxCobrarCL ItemSeleccionado
{
    get
    {
        return _ItemSeleccionado;
    }
    set
    {
        _ItemSeleccionado= value;
        ActualizaImporteAcumulado();
    }
}
```

Con esto, cada vez que cambies de fila, el valor de tu total se deberia actualizar.

Comment: muchas gracias @gbianchi, lo voy a intentar y te comento

Comment: perfecto, efectivamente con tu sugerencia @gbianchi, voy seleccionando en el checkbox las facturas que quiera totalizar y se va calculando correctamente el acumulado, el único detalle es que DEBO cambiar de renglón para que se totalice

Comment: SI. Por eso te lo aclare en la respuesta. Si no queres hacer eso, hay que trabajar con eventos por todos lados, y es un peligro de memoria.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes declarar la lista como un objeto en si y colocar el total como una propiedad de la lista:

```
public class CuentasxCobrarCL
{
    //[...]
}
public class CuentasCollection : ObservableCollection<CuentasxCobrarCL>
{
    public float TotalPago()
    {
        float total = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < this.Count; i++)
        {
            if (this[i].seleccionada)
            {
                total += this[i].importepago;
            }
        }

        return total;
    }
}
```

Luego, en el ViewModel en el evento propertyChanged va a actualizar ese valor automáticamente porque estará dentro de la lista

```
private CuentasCollection _cuentasxcobrar = new CuentasCollection();
public CuentasCollection CuentasxCobrar
{
    set
    {
        _cuentasxcobrar = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("CuentasxCobrar");

    }
    get { return _cuentasxcobrar; }
}
```

No pretendo ser la respuesta, pero creo que te puede ayudar si sabes aplicarlo.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu aporte @Leodev, lo reviso y comento